# Role of FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO in FCGI-Applications

Tags: c, sockets, fastcgi

I read the fcgi spec but still have problems understanding how the communication between:

```
web-Server <-> FCGI-Server <-> Application
```

works. The [FastCGI specification](https://fastcgi-archives.github.io/FastCGI_Specification.html) states, that the "Web-Server" leaves a file-descriptor `FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO (0)` which can be used to read the fcgi-packets. But how should that work, if the FCGI-Server lives on a different server than the webserver? This sounds to me like that the specification assumes, that the FCGI-Process is hosted on the same system as the web-server or confuses web-server with fcgi-server.

This is my current understanding of the fcgi-livecycle:

1. Web-Server receives an HTTP request and starts a fcgi request to a preconfigured socket/network address, let's say: `192.168.20.2:9090`.
2. The FastCGI-Application/Server listens on port 9090 for incoming requests and accept connections. No `FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO` as stated by the specification and no file-descriptor/socket created by the Web-Server. The fcgi server does that without any preexisting socket. It's responsible for multiplexing in/out data.
3. If the FCGI-Server itself does not implement an application, the server, which is acting as a Responder, spawns a new process with stdin, stdout piped to the FastCGI server. If the CGI-Application writes something to stdout, the FastCGI process encapsulates the data in fcgi-packets.

How does the lifecycle really work? Which parties are involved? Where does the `FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO` come into play? Why does the specification say the web-server leaves a socket/fd on which the application should call Accept(). For me, that makes absolutely no sense, because if the web-server creates a listen-socket, the other end has to call connect to establish a connection, but normally the web-server is responsible for establishing the FCGI-Connection. The FCGI-Server(/Application) only responds to the Connection-Request by calling Accept().

Answer (score 2):

I was also very confused when I was reading the spec and trying to fully understand FastCGI. I think I figured it out.

The spec assumes that FastCGI applications are stand-alone executables, similar to classic CGI executables, which get spawned and receive a socket over pre-defined descriptor numbers (in case of CGI, descriptors 0 and 1, and in case of FastCGI descriptor 0, with a difference that FastCGI executable is long-lived and expected to call accept() on a given socket in a loop, and then speak binary protocol over resulting sockets).

But the spec does account for FastCGI executable to be spawned either by the Web server (specifically FastCGI process manager built into Web server) or by the external FastCGI process manager. In fact, the FastCGI executable is required to check the peer IP address of the connection returned from accept() if it is a member of allowed Web server IPs passed in FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS. This scenario only happens when the executable is spawned by the external FastCGI process manager.

The external FastCGI process manager works by creating a TCP or Unix domain socket (to receive connections from a Web server) on startup, doing listen() on that socket and spawning FastCGI executables (during startup, or on the first request) with that socket passed as descriptor 0. In case the FastCGI executable is single-threaded (most likely case) it would need to spawn several instances. Still, the same socket would be passed to all instances and they would concurrently accept() connections on that socket (this is the classic Unix pre-fork model). Notice that they directly accept() on that socket, the process manager is not really involved in the data path. It only serves to create an initial listening socket and manage the lifecycle of the spawned processes.

The internal FastCGI process manager works similarly, with Unix domain sockets.

With modern setups like PHP-FPM, the above model of separation between process manager (either external or internal) and FastCGI executables is not used, a single external executable is responsible for listening and handling FastCGI requests.